# What is the correct way to type props in a Functional Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, components, react-props

**Example #1**

```
import React, { FC, ReactNode } from 'react';

type AccordionProps = {
  title: string;
  children: ReactNode;
};

const Accordion: FC<AccordionProps> = ({ children, title }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h3>{title}</h3>
      <div>{children}</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Accordion;
```

**Example #2**

```
import React, { FC, ReactNode } from 'react';

type AccordionProps = {
  title: string;
  children: ReactNode;
};

const Accordion = ({ children, title }: AccordionProps) => {
  return (
    <>
      <h3>{title}</h3>
      <div>{children}</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Accordion;
```

I've had a question for a time but I don't know where to look for an answer.

What is the correct way to type props in a React Functional Component: using `FC<>` or as plain TypeScript parameters type?

Both of them work correctly, but I don't know if there exists a convention or rules to do it?

Comment: Wrong question maybe? Are you asking "Should I use React Function Component Interface (FC) when writing function components using TypeScript?" - If so, this is purely an opinion question and will likely get closed.

Comment: Even though this question shouldn't be on Stack Overflow, in the first example, you set a type for the function as a Functional Component, meaning this function will return some JSX. Meanwhile in the second example, Typescript will assume `any` for the function, and you just set the props types directly. I would suggest going with the first example, since that will correctly mark the the function as a Funtional Component.

Comment: See [fb/cra#8177](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177) for a detailed explanation of the many downsides of `FC`, and single benefit.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.